# sites for research notepad online

Tags: web-apps, search-engine

I am looking for a notepad cloud-based app for research projects but I couldn't find any app which provides all the features that I need:

1. multi purpose note taking
2. markdown note taking
3. sub-directory options.

Easily take all sort of notes:

- Collect research results and share them
- Centralize your project data and re-use them
- Quickly organize your thoughts in idea boxes
- Keep track of your information in a smart way
- Make intelligent To Do lists

Other features:

rich text, links, images, sounds, files, colors, application launcher...
Objects can be edited, copied, dragged.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it better, it sounds like a quick cut-and-paste job (why suddenly *your* instead of *mine*, *objects* instead of *notes*?). Divide your requirements into must have/could have. Remove the subjective phrases like *a smart way* - that's not a hard requirement. What are *idea boxes*? What price are you willing to pay? Etcetera...

Comment: And your question [may already be answered here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+note+taking) - do research before asking.

Answer (score 1):

[Twiddla](http://www.twiddla.com/), [Vyew](http://vyew.com/s/) are all cloud based app which is suitable for collaborative meeting note taking.

If you are looking for only text with Collaborative Text editing and a free solutions which can work on cloud you can refer to ether pad. Features are available here for your quick [reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/online-collaborative-editing-etherpad/).

Comment: Vyew is not available now.